# Paperclip image uploads keep showing up sideways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a form that uses the paperclip gem to upload photos but they show sideways on my index page. Is there anything that will keep the images from flipping after they upload?

Comment: Please share your relevant code

Comment: I am having a similar problem (in python),  someone suggested that it may be dues to a settings on camera phones to automatically orient the pictures.